# I am tryign to create a zip of my wp folder but getting error

Tags: wordpress, php-ziparchive

What I am trying to do is creating a zip file

```
    public function createFilesBackup()
   {
        $dir = home_path();
        $sitePath = realpath($dir);
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($sitePath),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );
        $zipName = 'backup_'.date('Y-m-d').'.zip';

        $zipfileName = $sitePath."/wp-content/uploads/".$zipName;
       
        $zip->open($zipfileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
        foreach ($files as $name => $file)
        {
            if (!$file->isDir())
            {
                $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($sitePath) + 1);
                $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
            }
        }
        $zip->close();
 
        return get_site_url()."/".$zipName;
   }
```

And this is what I am getting Can anyone help me out I would be a great

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: SplFileInfo::isDir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/abdulbasit/web/checkout-demo.wholisticleather.com/public_html/..) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/abdulbasit/web/checkout-demo.wholisticleather.com/public_html:/home/abdulbasit/tmp) in /home/abdulbasit/web/checkout-demo.wholisticleather.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/MerchantypayWPBackup/MerchantypayWPBackup.php:66 Stack trace: #0 /home/abdulbasit/web/checkout-demo.wholisticleather.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/MerchantypayWPBackup/MerchantypayWPBackup.php(66): SplFileInfo->isDir() #1 /home/abdulbasit/web/checkout-demo.wholisticleather.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/MerchantypayWPBackup/cron.php(23): MerchantypayWPBackup->createFilesBackup('/home/abdulbasi...', '/home/abdulbasi...') #2 {main} thrown in